# Running two BackgroundWorkers together

Tags: c#, winforms, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to run 2 BackgroundWorkers in parallel. How can I implement it?  In my code below, backgroundWorker2 doesn't work:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does work.  What you are doing in the DoWork methods for those two workers might not be working.  You didn't post that code.

Comment: I put breakpoint at the first of backgroundWorker2 do work , it doesn't work @larsTech

Comment: Pay attention to the second part of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) instead. Newer way of doing things like this.

Pseudocode using [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => SomeMethod(), () => SomeOtherMethod());
```

Pseudocode with [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
async Task SomeMethod() {  }
async Task SomeOtherMethod() {  }  

Task task1 = SomeMethod();
Task task2 = SomeOtherMethod();
await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
// get results task1.Result and task2.Result
```